# What is this tool that was once used to teach beginner level BASIC?

Tags: basic

In the early 1980's there was a small handheld device that looked like a calculator. It was a tool to teach beginner level programming in BASIC. Its ad slogan was "keep it near you". I never had one and I have forgotten the exact brand name. It was in the American market. It seemed to be marketed at people who knew nothing about computers or programming; the ads said that you could go from knowing nothing to being competent in programming in a few weeks.

Did anyone seriously learn to program from using this? Or was it an obscure failure that become a footnote in tech history? This is getting obscure. What was the tool? It was awhile ago.

Comment: Do you want us to identify this for you? Otherwise (if this is about users' personal experiences), this is not really a good fit for the site, and will be closed. (Hint: [edit].)

Comment: "the ads said that you could go from knowing nothing to being competent in programming in a few weeks" - they still do. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0789757745/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=aeebc627-7ecf-4129-8c0c-1d437f271eca&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0672327112&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=GT4QRHFWZGEFA6G11GTW&pf_rd_r=GT4QRHFWZGEFA6G11GTW&pf_rd_p=aeebc627-7ecf-4129-8c0c-1d437f271eca

Comment: Are you thinking of something from the [Tandy Pocket Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandy_Pocket_Computer) range (actually, rebadged Sharp or Casio products)?

Comment: Those did BASIC commands. But I don't think that they are it; I'm thinking of something more limited that basically taught BASIC and that was all it did. But it did look a pocket calculator in size and shape and it was easily portable.